# Error when Creating Layer Package in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, layer-package

I'm trying to create a layer package from a feature layer (whose data source is a feature class) using arcpy. However, I keep getting the following error:

Object: Error in executing tool

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Data/"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
print "environments set"

lpk = "layerPackage.lpk"
summary = "A summary"
tags = "tag1", "tag2"
print "layer package variables defined"

dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", dataFrame)
print layers

for lyr in layers:
    try:
        if lyr.name == "Layer_I_Want":
            print "converting Layer_I_Want to lpk"
            arcpy.PackageLayer_management(lyr, lpk, "CONVERT", "PRESERVE_ARCSDE", 
            "#", "ALL", "ALL", "CURRENT", "#", summary, tags)
            print "lpk created"
    except Exception as e: print(e)

mxd.save()
```

How do I fix it?

I've tried different combinations of "CONVERT"/"PRESERVE" but still get the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure, but one thing I see is that you're allowing overwrite outputs before setting your workspace, is this keeping your outputs from being written due to duplicate files?

Comment: Per the doc, the first CONVERT is not relevant when using SDE data. Use  "CONVERT_ARCSDE". Also, try making lpk a full path  using os.path.join (workspace,lpkName.lpk) http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/package-layer.htm

Comment: So i made the changes you guys suggested but still received the same error. However, I did manage to get it to work simply by combining tag1 and tag2 as a single string. Below is my final code for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Data/"
workspace = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
print "environments set"

lpkName = "layerPackage"
lpk = os.path.join(workspace+lpkName+".lpk")
summary = "A summary"
tags = "tag1, tag2"
print "layer package variables defined"

dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", dataFrame)

for lyr in layers:
  try:
    if lyr.name == "Layer_I_Want":
        print "converting Layer_I_Want to lpk"
        arcpy.PackageLayer_management(lyr, lpk, "PRESERVE", "CONVERT_ARCSDE", 
        "#", "ALL", "ALL", "CURRENT", "#", summary, tags)
        print "lpk created"
except Exception as e: print(e)

mxd.save()
```